# broken module block in magento 1.9.3.9 how do i debug the issue

Tags: php, debugging, magento, module

So i understand there may be many other questions regarding my module does not show on frontend. But they all seem to be related to camelcase mistakes and incorrect formating of config.xml and system.xml thing is i havent touched these.

I have been working on my magento store and made a lot of changes recently to my template and modules and recently broke my gifts module on the checkout page

my main question is how do i debug this i see no errors in the error_log

i'm trying to load the following block in the checkout page within my template

**magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/ig_cartgifts/gifts.phtml**

I'm using a theme but this has not been an issue in the past that the phtml is in the base default template, i have tried adding it to my theme file structure also

I'm calling this from my cart.phtml in my theme

magento/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

```html
<div class="gift-container-content" style="display: block;">  
   <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('gifts')): ?>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('gifts'); // IG GiftCart module - nothing to do with Meigee or B&W theme ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

this is the block i'm trying to call to debug why its not loading

**magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/ig_cartgifts/gifts.phtml**

```html
    <h3><?php  echo $this->__('debug') ?></h3>
```

**following is my config.xml**

magento/app/code/community/IG/CartGifts/etc/config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <IG_CartGifts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </IG_CartGifts>
    </modules>
    
 <frontend>
  <layout>
            <updates>
                <ig_cartgifts>
                    <file>ig_cartgifts.xml</file>
                </ig_cartgifts>
            </updates>
  </layout>    
    </frontend>      

    <global>
        <models>
            <ig_cartgifts>
                <class>IG_CartGifts_Model</class>
            </ig_cartgifts>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <ig_cartgifts_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>IG_CartGifts</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </ig_cartgifts_setup>

            <ig_cartgifts_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </ig_cartgifts_write>
            
            <ig_cartgifts_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </ig_cartgifts_read>
        </resources>
        
        <blocks>
            <ig_cartgifts>
                <class>IG_CartGifts_Block</class>
            </ig_cartgifts>
        </blocks>
        
        <helpers>
            <ig_cartgifts>
                <class>IG_CartGifts_Helper</class>
            </ig_cartgifts>
        </helpers>
        
        <events>
   <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <ig_cartgifts>
                        <class>ig_cartgifts/observer</class>
                        <method>onCheckoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
                    </ig_cartgifts>
                </observers>
         </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
         
         <checkout_cart_save_after>
    <observers>
     <ig_cartgifts>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>ig_cartgifts/observer</class>
      <method>onCheckoutCartSaveAfter</method>
     </ig_cartgifts>
    </observers>
   </checkout_cart_save_after>
   <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
                <observers>
                    <ig_cartgifts>
                        <class>ig_cartgifts/observer</class>
                        <method>onCheckoutCartUpdateItemsAfter</method>
                    </ig_cartgifts>
                </observers>
         </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
  </events>
    </global>
    
    <adminhtml>
  <translate>
   <modules>
    <ig_cartgifts>
     <files>
      <default>IG_CartGifts.csv</default>
     </files>
    </ig_cartgifts>
   </modules>
  </translate>
  <acl>
   <resources>
    <admin>
     <children>
      <system>
       <children>
        <config>
         <children>
          <ig_cartgifts translate="title" module="ig_cartgifts">
           <title>IG CartGifts</title>
           <sort_order>50</sort_order>
          </ig_cartgifts>
         </children>
        </config>
       </children>
      </system>
     </children>
    </admin>
   </resources>
  </acl>
    </adminhtml>
  
 <default>
  <ig_cartgifts>
   <general>
    <enabled>1</enabled>
    <show_all>1</show_all>
    <show_notinstock>1</show_notinstock>
   </general>
  </ig_cartgifts>
 </default>
</config>
```

magento/app/code/community/IG/CartGifts/etc/system.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
  <ig translate="label" module="ig_cartgifts">
            <label>IdealiaGroup</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
  </ig>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
  <ig_cartgifts translate="label" module="ig_cartgifts">
   <label>IG CartGifts</label>
   <tab>ig</tab>
   <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
   <sort_order>10</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
   <groups>
    <general translate="label">
     <label>General</label>
     <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
     <fields>
      <enabled translate="label">
       <label>Enable CartGifts</label>
       <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
       <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
       <sort_order>10</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      </enabled>
      <show_all translate="label">
       <label>Show all gifts</label>
       <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
       <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
       <sort_order>20</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      </show_all>
      <show_notinstock translate="label">
       <label>Show not in stock gifts</label>
       <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
       <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
       <sort_order>30</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
      </show_notinstock>
     </fields>
    </general>
   </groups>
  </ig_cartgifts>
    </sections>
</config>
```

and the xml in the etc modules folder

magento/app/etc/modules/IG_CartGifts.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <IG_CartGifts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
  </IG_CartGifts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

so how do i debug why its not loading if i put the site into debug profiler it doesnt put any errors into error_log

my suspision was block permissions but it was working fine previously without block permissions and i've made so many changes now i'd have to go too far back to see what caused it

thanks